# Facebook Create a One Line Story template with images

Tags: facebook, feed

Is it possible to add a small image (around 16x16px) to a One Line Story template in front of the username? I am using the facebook tool to create the feed, and can't figure out how I can get a small image in front of the one line story. It works fine with the code below for larger stories, but not the one line stories?

```
{"images":[{"src":"http://pad.thedigitalmovement.com/_blaise/2007-06-15-dgen-breakfast.jpg", "href":"http://www.facebook.com"}, {"src": "http://pad.thedigitalmovement.com/_blaise/2007-06-13-roger-waters.jpg", "href":"http://www.facebook.com"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not possible. Though the post will be showed on the Wall with your application logo, which you can set or change in the developer app on your applications settings.

Comment: I have set the facebook connect image which is about 80x20 px, is that the image you are talking about, or is there another place I can upload an application image? 
Might it be because my image is too large that it doesn't get shown on the feed in the one line stories?

Comment: You're talking about the "Facebook Connect Logo" on the "Connect" tab in Edit Settings. I think the application logo is on the "Basic" tab called "Icon". Does it work when you add 16x16 image there?

Comment: I missed the icons under the basic tab. Thanks a lot:)